# How to use logical functions with %>% operator (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr, logic

I was wondering how to use logical (for example `which`, `any`, `all`) functions with `%>%` operator from `dplyr` package in R. I have a vector of values

`aaa <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)`

I would like to find out which of them are equal to `4`. When I try this:

`aaa == 4 %>% which(.)`

I get the following error:

`Error in which(.) : argument to 'which' is not logical`

The same goes with other functions which require logical vector as an argument, such as `all` or `any`.

`aaa == 4 %>% any`

`[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE`

`Warning message: In any(.) : coercing argument of type 'double' to logical`

Comment: What is your dplyr version?

Comment: `%>%` isn't `dplyr` operator.

Comment: Yes, but it's imported by `dplyr` ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's just an operator precedence issue.  The `%>%` operator has lower precedence than other operators such as `==`,  so what you're actually doing with `aaa == 4 %>% which` is passing `4` to the `which` function ...

```
(aaa == 4) %>% which
```

seems to work just fine ...

This use of `%>%` seems a little odd/unnecessary, but maybe that's just because you've isolated it from your workflow in order to create a reproducible example.  Maybe you could say a little more about the context?

Comment: What is your dplyr version?

Answer (score 4):

Use brackets around logical operations.

```
aaa <- sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE)
(aaa == 4) %>% which(.)
[1]  7  9 10
(aaa == 4) %>% which()
[1]  7  9 10
(aaa == 4) %>% any()
[1] TRUE
```